# Starbucks Mobile Navigation with Cubic Bezier Transitions

Tags: mobile, css, navigation

I'm trying to basically replicate the Starbucks mobile navigation but I can't figure out how to get their smooth slide transition when you click the three lines. It looks like they're using CSS3 transitions to achieve this animation but I can't replicate it.

I've got the same result but without it animating because CSS3 does not animate display: inherit.

Here is my JSFiddle, can anyone improve it with a CSS3 cubic bezier transition like Starbucks.com is using on their mob navigation? (you'll have to resize your window to see their mob nav obviously)

p.s. this needs to be CSS3, no jQuery animation please :-)

http://jsfiddle.net/zQxNd/2/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Best approach I've encountered is to set the default style of the hidden menu to:

```
display:block;
overflow:hidden;
height:0;
```

then in your .open set the height of the element:

```
height: 200px;
```

I edited your fiddle to show: http://jsfiddle.net/zQxNd/3/

Also, it's probably best to write a quick jQuery function to set the height of through jQuery -- it's not ideal, but it's the best solution I've found with the tools we have.

EDIT: and for getting the exact speed of the animation, you can play with this awesome little app: http://cubic-bezier.com/

Once you get the timing down, you can replace your `ease-in` in the transition declaration with something like this:

```
transition: all 1s cubic-bezier(.17,.67,.83,.67)
```

Comment: Thanks Thomas, I think you're right, it's probably the best solution. The other thing which kind of worked was adding padding on to the .open class which would give an animation effect of a kind, but not as smooth as animating the height. Good tip with calculating the height via jQuery, that will make it robust. Was just keen to pass the animation over to CSS3 rather than deal with toggle states and the complication of expanding windows.

I've already been using cubic-bezier.com already - another awesome tool from Lea Verou :-)

Comment: @Thomas for some reason I can't get this to work, I have even copied the code from the fiddle into my html 5 page and can't get it to work. Does anyone have a working online example??

Comment: @AshleyBriscoe are you using all the proper vendor prefixes in your css file (eg, -webkit-transition: all 1s cubic-bezier(.17,.67,.83,.67); etc...? And are you sure the browser your using supports css transitions?

Comment: @thomas I have copied the code exact and I am viewing in the latest version of Chrome. I can't even get the open and closed states to toggle

Comment: I have copied the code into a new fiddle and it works but doesn't work with in my test document, shall I create a question and point you to it??

Comment: @Thomas I have it working, mistake on my part. Thank you for this great insight. One question do you have an example of how to calculate the menu height using jquery?